# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'defaultPrevented') in bootstrap 5 toast

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, bootstrap-5

using custom hook to show and hide toast, it works fine when `showTost` is invoked in Toast component button when use this hook outside i.e in App component button getting error

```
TypeError
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'defaultPrevented')
Toast.show
https://izso9.csb.app/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js:3399:19
showToast
/src/useToast.js:11:12
   8 | 
   9 |  const showToast = () => {
  10 |    bsToast = new Toast(myToast, { autohide: true, delay: 1000 });
> 11 |    bsToast.show();
     |           ^
  12 |  };
  13 | 
  14 |  const hideToast = () => {
View compiled
```

useToast.js

```
import { Toast } from "bootstrap";
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function useToast() {
  const toastRef = useRef();
  let myToast = toastRef.current;
  let bsToast = Toast.getInstance(myToast);

  const showToast = () => {
    bsToast = new Toast(myToast, { autohide: true, delay: 1000 });
    bsToast.show();
  };

  const hideToast = () => {
    bsToast = new Toast(myToast, { autohide: true });
    bsToast.hide();
  };
  return { toastRef, showToast, hideToast };
}
```

[CODE SANDBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-toast-using-bootstrap-5-izso9?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I see the same error clicking either button.

Comment: Because your `toastRef.current` is `undefined`. You can also just pass the element id. `new Toast("#toastId")` for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't pass the `toastRef` from the App component and it's undefined. If you add this piece of code inside the App component, it's going to work

```
<div
    className="toast position-absolute bottom-0 end-0 m-4"
    role="alert"
    ref={toastRef}
  >
    <div className="toast-header">
      <strong className="me-auto">Bootstrap 5</strong>
      <small>4 mins ago</small>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn-close"
        onClick={hideToast}
        aria-label="Close"
      ></button>
    </div>
    <div className="toast-body">Hello, world! This is a toast message.</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: If I want to call toast on any success response based on api status code , how can I do that ?

Comment: That's a broad question. That would depend on your implementation so I can't answer that but for sure you have to abstract the toast component and call it wherever you want

Answer (score 1):

I used bootstrap 5 with Vuejs and had the same error. I found that the same error appears when Toast is created in one place(on component creation) and I'm calling toast.show() in another place(on component update).

Here is example:

```
export default {
  props: {
     toastHeader: String,
     toastBody: String,
     isHidden: Boolean
 }, 
 data() {
     return {
         toast: null
     }
 },
 created(){
     //here toast initialized when component is created
     this.toast = new Toast(document.getElementById("bootstrap-toast"));
 },
 updated(){
     //component is updated, so toast is recreated in DOM. Error thrown
     if(!this.isHidden) this.toast.show();
 }  
}
```

To resolve this I did the following:

```
export default {
  props: {
      toastHeader: String,
      toastBody: String,
      isHidden: Boolean
  },
  updated(){
      let toast = new Toast(document.getElementById("bootstrap-toast"));
      if(!this.isHidden) toast.show();
  }  
}
```

Probably in your case, there is the same case. So, **toastRef.current** might contain something invalid at the moment toast show / hide triggered. Try to use  **document.getElementById** inside new Toast() just to check if it is the exact case as mine. I know that it seems weird to use **document.getElementById** . At least it will give you an idea where is the problem is.

Comment: wnzrgekl.cklgebrc, just a comment.  I ran into this as well. However i believe if you move the creation of the toast in your first example from the "created" method to the VueJS "mounted" method the problem may go away.  At least it did for me!